# WPF dynamic resource not found in MergedDictionary but outside it is fine

Tags: c#, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a main Class (with an MainView.xaml) that dynamically loads various other Pages long after the MainView has been shown.

So MainView.xaml has following style defined:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="ErrorTemplate" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

In one of the loaded pages I had following declaration:

```
<Page.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="ErrorStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource ErrorTemplate"/>
  </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

This worked fine.

Now I needed to load other resources from an external XAML file so I used `MergedDictionaries`.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Guaranteed to not have an ErrorTemplate key -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MoreStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary>
              <Style x:Key="ErrorStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource ErrorTemplate"/>
              </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

And now I started to receive the message that `ErrorTemplate` could not be resolved.

Moving it outside of the `MergedDictionary` fixed the problem again.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MoreStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Style x:Key="ErrorStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
          <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource ErrorTemplate"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

What is happening here?